# Anchor links not working properly

Tags: xhtml, anchor

I have a tooltip that has a link to an anchor but it seems like it is not going to the right anchor. Rollover the person and click on the "[+]" inside the tooltip.

To view the sample click [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/about-phil/team)

Comment: Why are you using background images for the pictures of the people you are talking about? They are content! Use `<img>`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
<a id="david" ...>
```

on the links.  That's the first match for a `#david` URL - that will match either an `id` or a `name`.  The `<a name=...` anchors lower down the document are being ignored.

You need to rename either the `id`s or the `name`s, so that there's only one element with an `id` of `david`, **or** one anchor with a `name` of `david`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two anchors with the same identifier.

The first using the modern approach:

```
<a id="laurence" title="Laurence Rabino - Web Multimedia">Laurence Rabino</a>
```

and the second using the Netscape 4 compatible approach (which, for some reason, is contentless):

```
<a name="laurence"></a>
```

The browser scrolls to the first one.

Change the identifiers so they don't conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have all of your `id`'s defined for the div's that contain everyone's picture. For example:

```
<a id="laurence">Laurence Rabino</a>
```

You need to move the ID's down to their appropriate locations in the "summary" section, so that when you click on one it links to that person's information. For example:

```
<p id="laurence">
```